# Views reverse relationship with groupwise max

Tags: views

In my view I need to show only one (most recent) related entity from the base entity of the view. Specifically I work with **crm-core contacts** which work with **crm-core activity**. Each contact has one or more activities, and in the view I need only the most recent activity.

The problem is that the reference field is *NOT* from the contact to its activities but rather from an activity to its contacts. (This is how it works in CRM-Core)

If the reference was the other-way-around (from contact to activities) I would use `views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max`.

Did anybody implement the same like `views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max` but for **reverse** references? Something like a combination of `views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max` with `views_handler_relationship_entity_reverse`